# How to Disable Remote desktop connection over internet on Windows server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp, internet, sonicwall

We are using Windows server 2012. I have to disable RDP over internet. But Remote desktop should be used in Intranet.Is there any way to disable? 
Note: We are also using Sonicwall firewall.

Comment: I hope you're not the admin..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then the obvious answer is to disable outside access to your RDP port (typically 3389).

This question is a bit surprising since the only ways it could be reached from the outside would be if the server was directly connected to the Internet (not firewalled), or if you had previously set a port forwarding rule in your firewall configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Can you explain the steps for to disable outside access to RDP port?

Comment: This site is for systems and network administrators and therefore expects its users to know these basic operations.  That said, I've found you their instructions to block a port: https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw8110

Comment: But as I mentioned in my answer, it is not normal that you'd have to block that port unless you opened it in the first place.  You should therefore consult with your network administrator.

Comment: Do you have a firewall between your host and your public IP address space?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone else that if you aren't allowing traffic to the server through your firewall there is nothing to worry about.

If you want to use Windows Firewall to block it though you can create a new Inbound Rule (the default will block Edge Traversal), allow port 3389, and from there you can limit the external and internal subnets that are able to connect on that port.

Answer (score 0):

My Window server (VPS) comes with a VNC but not with an external firewall. Therefore, I used the following article to block RDP (actually, I have setup a secure cloudflared RDP tunnel as well).

https://www.action1.com/how-to-block-or-allow-tcp-ip-port-in-windows-firewall/

This way I am able to direct internet traffic to RDP port.